# Why does saying "3pm" get changed to "In the afternoon early" in Roblox chat?

Tags: roblox

A few days ago my friend was apparently going to bed at 3pm. I asked her why she was going to bed at 3pm but it was in quotes so I wrote the question and "3pm" separate but it converted to *"in the afternoon early"*.

Why does this happen in Roblox chat?

Comment: I don't play roblox but it seems that previously there was something called [Safe Chat](http://roblox.wikia.com/wiki/Safe_Chat) which would only allow you to type certain phrases, it's possible that there is a new system that replaces certain phrases (like time entries) with non-committal phrases like 'in the afternoon'.

Comment: @Robotnik I don't think this is an automatic replacement; your edit seems to be assuming a specific behaviour that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Frank -  Fair enough, I'm not sure how else one would interpret *"...I wrote the question and "3pm" separate but it was in quotes so I said "in the afternoon early..."* as anything other than that the output (what he 'said') was different to what he typed ("3pm"). It certainly wouldn't be the first chat-bot which replaces known phrases with other text. If you know of something else that might cause this (or have a different interpretation) please let us know.

Comment: Automatic replacement is common as a filter type.  It really does sound like you are describing that.

Comment: If I had to guess, it’s for child safety. Roblox is played by a lot of children, so I imagine they wouldn’t want adults telling kids a specific time to meet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom filter created by whoever made the game you were playing. Roblox has never, and will never, manually replace what you said with something else except for hashes (#).

Comment: And, unless your stars are particularly well-aligned, the Roblox chat filter will change "3 p.m." into "#####", so it's to your advantage to write "early afternoon" instead (and hope that doesn't get changed into "##### #########"). That said, I've never met a Roblox game that even attempted to mess with the chat filters, because it's such an impenetrable moving target.

Comment: Aye, this is certainly an edge case, but an edge case is still very real.

Comment: Why do they censor times?

Comment: @inakilbss Could be used to derive timezone, and thus location.

Comment: Considering timezones literally go from pole to pole, I think that's overkill.

Comment: @inakilbss Welcome to roblox! Enjoy your stay.